# Не могу разобраться с запросом на обновления

Tags: php, sql

Здесь вывожу нужные мне данные:

```
$senders = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "sum_back_newposhta` WHERE  `id`  < 100")->rows;          
        $ei_numbers = array();
               foreach ($senders as $sender) {
            $ei_numbers[] = array(
                'DocumentNumber' => $sender['ttn'],
                'Phone' => $sender['phone'],
            );
        }
```

Здесь передаю

```
$documents = $novaposhta->tracking($ei_numbers);
```

Здесь достаю то что мне нужно

```
foreach ($documents as $document) {
                $set_arr[] = array(
                    'sum_back' => $document['RedeliverySum'],
                );


                if ($set_arr) {
                    $this->db->query("UPDATE `".DB_PREFIX."sum_back_newposhta` SET `sum_back`='" . $this->db->escape($document['RedeliverySum']) . " WHERE ttn = '" . $number_ttn ."'");
                    echo $document['RedeliverySum']." OK\n\r<br>";
                }
            }
```

Но обновления не работает из `WHERE ttn = '" . $number_ttn .` Как нужно сделать что бы обновления записывалось в нужный id ?

Comment: Использовать вместо `ttn = 'smth'` условие `id = 123` пробовали?

Comment: Побывал вот так   WHERE id = '" .  $senders[$document['Number']]['id'] но не проходит запрос, я так понимаю мне нужно правильно составить вот эту часть запроса что бы у мне проверялось какая сумма соответствует нужному id вот это не могу понять

Answer (score 0):

Предположу что это ошибка синтаксиса:

```
SET `sum_back`='" . $this->db->escape($document['RedeliverySum']) . " WHERE
```

Открыли скобку `'` но не закрыли после `".$this->db->escape($document['RedeliverySum'])."`